# Border around textSpan of RichText

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have a `RichText` widget that contains some `TextSpan.` Around a `TextSpan` widget, I want to place a border around it. Also, I want this to work on the web, but currently from my method this only works on mobile.

Expected: I want to achieve the following.
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Result by using this code:

```
    Paint paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.blue
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

RichText(
   text: TextSpan(children: [
       TextSpan(text: text1),
       TextSpan(text: text2, style: TextStyle(background: paint)),
       TextSpan(text: text3, )
  ]))
```

[image]

please help!!!

If this is not clear, to simply put it, I just want to have a border around the highlighted portion and remove the highlight in the figure below without changing anything else

[image]

Comment: Wrap your RichText with Container and give border to your selected Text :)

Comment: I don't want to add a border to the entire RichText, but individual textSpan's within a richText so that I can customize the text in between the same paragraph and get the result like mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Kuldip, I just checked this dart pad and could reproduce this issue. Looks like a bug in flutter-web since you mentioned it works in mobile.

Comment: Maybe you can raise and issue in github for this with this sample code.

Comment: I will remember to do so, but still, I can't get the desired results in android as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the op's issue is happening in web, due to a bug in flutter-web itself, this cannot be solved as of now. However following is answer contains a generic solution which should work in flutter web when its fixed.

***New Answer: 04.03.2020***
In order to achieve the effect you want there is an option called `blendMode` for which you have to `BlendMode.difference` in the `Paint` object. You can use this to achieve a result similar to what you want.

[image]

Code for the same

```dart
 TextSpan(
          style: TextStyle(
            background: Paint()
              ..color = Colors.blue
              ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
              ..strokeWidth = 2.0
              ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.bevel
              ..blendMode = BlendMode.difference,
          ),
          text:
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
        ),
```

Note: I am also trying out another painstaking way of manually drawing the bounds just for the sake of it. If you come across some other solutions, please do share it here. :) Hope this helps you.

***Old Answer***

So depending on the context of the run time, I switch the text style. For web this passes a list of `TextDecorations` like `underline` and `overline`. This doesn't cover the ends of the text, but I believe better than fully highlighted text as in your results. There are some additional options like `decorationThickness`, and `decorationStyle` to tinker with.

Here is how the solution looks in flutter web mode.

[image]

```
Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(text: 'bounded text1'),
          TextSpan(
            text: ' Will this work ',
            style: kIsWeb
                ? TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.combine(
                        [TextDecoration.overline, TextDecoration.underline]),
                    decorationColor: Colors.blue,
                  )
                : TextStyle(
                    background: paint,
                  ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'bounded text 3',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I would extract these style to a constant and dynamically apply them based on the current running context like android or web.. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, but making it work for the web is not my number 1 issue, my priority is to make it look like the first figure mentioned in the question at least on android and if possible on the web later on. Do you have any idea, how I can make that work? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for all the help, there is one small problem in that as well, it only works on a black background and still some artifacts are present in doing that. I want to make it work in any scenario. Thanks for all your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text inside container  like that

```
return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(),
  ), 
        child: Text(
          "text",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: I am searching for a way to highlight random texts in the middle of a paragraph, not just an individual text widget. Hence, this method is not for me. Thanks for your help though. :D